# Sum date interval Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a two-column list of data. One with Date, and one with a Quantity value. I want to make a function who sums the last 7 days at any time (date inverval). I'm struggling to get Data.today - 7 days in Google spredasheet. Please see the attached spreadsheet. Would really appreciate your help.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApcTruAehxiFdEV4MEt1Q3RYLVU1c29LSFFIbUV1RFE&usp=sharing

Correct output should 22

Comment: How come your output should be 22? What is the sum range date? is it today or other date which should be specified in a cell? Can you explain a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it:

=SUM(FILTER(B2:B;A2:A>today()-7))

Source: http://spreadsheetpro.net/how-to-make-sumifs-countifs-averagifs-functions-in-google-spreadsheet/

An easier solution would be a SUMIF function, which is available in 'new google spreadsheet" (NGS) which launched late 2013. However NGS does not yet support the Google Spreadsheet API, which I'm dependent on for this spreadsheet. =SUM(FILTER(B2:B;A2:A>today()-7)) works for old google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be working but don't (I don't know why): =SUMIF(A2:A9;">TODAY()-7";B2:B9)

Workaround:

add in column C in each row: =A?>TODAY()-7

then formula will be: =SUMIF(C2:C9;"=TRUE";B2:B9)